# DATEDIF function with multiple criteria

Tags: excel-formula, nested, datediff, sumifs

I'm attempting to use a DATEDIF function to calculate the days of between dates for days of rest a team has. Below is a picture with the values manually inputed. DATEDIF function doesn't allow additional criteria to be used. I tried nesting it in a countif and sumif to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

[Days Rest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzD3w.png)

Comment: If you just want days you don't need datedif because you can just subtract the dates.

Comment: True but they're multiple teams, so it's impossible to fill down

Answer (score 1):

Your data appears sorted by date ascending. In B416 use this formula for the rest period (date minus previous date minus 1).,

```
'office 365 (and others) with MAXIFS
=if(countif(c$1:c415, c416), a416-maxifs(a$1:a415, c$1:c415, c416)-1, text(,))
'for xl versions without MAXIFS (xl2010 and above)
=if(countif(c$1:c415, c416), a416-aggregate(14, 6, (a$1:a415)/(c$1:c415=c416), 1)-1, text(,))
```

You should be able to copy that formula from B416 to B2 and fill down.